# Interpolación en una matriz 2d

Tags: python, imagen, matriz, interpolacion

estoy intentado realizar una interpolación sobre una matriz 2d donde la matriz tiene entre sus
valores ceros, los cuales deseo reemplazar estos valores con valores que estén cerca o al rededor de estos valores, he estado revisando varios ejemplos pero no he tenido éxito en mi búsqueda, he probado el siguiente código de interpolación,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

mymin,mymax = 0,3

X = np.linspace(mymin,mymax,4)

Y = np.linspace(mymin,mymax,4)

x,y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)


test = np.array([[ 1.2514318 , 0,  1.25148472,  1.25151133],
   [ 1.25087456,  0,  1.25092764,  1.25095435],
   [ 1.25031581,  1.25034238,  1.25036907,  0],
   [ 0,  1.24978222,  0,  1.24983587]])

f = interpolate.interp2d(x,y,test,kind='linear')

X_n = np.linspace(mymin,mymax,4)
Y_n = np.linspace(mymin,mymax,4)

test_n = f(X_n,Y_n)

print (test_n)

[[ 1.25143180e+00  2.77555756e-16  1.25148472e+00  1.25151133e+00]
[ 1.25087456e+00  2.49800181e-16  1.25092764e+00  1.25095435e+00]
[ 1.25031581e+00  1.25034238e+00  1.25036907e+00  1.38777878e-17]
[ 5.33635770e-17  1.24978222e+00 -1.11022302e-16  1.24983587e+00]]
```

Como se ve si funciona correctamente pero los lugares donde estaban los ceros , se volvió en una valor muy pequeño que no corresponde a sus valores que están a su alrededor, tendría una falla el modo como estoy interpolando?